# Binary to Integer -> Erlang

Tags: erlang, binary, integer

I have a binary M such that 34= will always be present and the rest may vary between any number of digits but will always be an integer.

```
M = [<<"34=21">>]
```

When I run this command I get an answer like

```
hd([X || <<"34=", X/binary >> <- M])

Answer -> <<"21">>
```

How can I get this to be an integer with the most care taken to make it as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
[<<"34=",X/binary>>] = M,
list_to_integer(binary_to_list(X)).
```

That yields the integer `21`

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do it?  Any idea why there is not a function to go directly from binary to integer?

Comment: because a binary is by default a set of integer. What you have done here is used the representation of integer characters which Erlang knows to interpret as a string. Basically a BIF to do it would 'binary_to_list_to_integer' because `<<X, _/binary>> = <<1,2,3>>` would already give you just '1' and that's pretty much binary-to-integer conversion, I guess.

Answer (score 21):

[As of R16B](http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B.readme), the BIF [`binary_to_integer/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_integer-1) can be used:

> **OTP-10300**
>
> Added four new bifs, `erlang:binary_to_integer/1,2`,
>             `erlang:integer_to_binary/1`, `erlang:binary_to_float/1` and
>             `erlang:float_to_binary/1,2`. These bifs work similarly to how
>             their list counterparts work, except they operate on
>             binaries. In most cases converting from and to binaries is
>             faster than converting from and to lists.
>
> These bifs are auto-imported into erlang source files and can
>             therefore be used without the erlang prefix.

So that would look like:

```
[<<"34=",X/binary>>] = M,
binary_to_integer(X).
```

Answer (score 2):

A string representation of a number can be converted by N-48. For multi-digit numbers you can fold over the binary, multiplying by the power of the position of the digit:

```
-spec to_int(binary()) -> integer().
to_int(Bin) when is_binary(Bin) ->
    to_int(Bin, {size(Bin), 0}).

to_int(_, {0, Acc}) ->
    erlang:trunc(Acc);
to_int(<<N/integer, Tail/binary>>, {Pos, Acc}) when N >= 48, N =< 57 ->
    to_int(Tail, {Pos-1, Acc + ((N-48) * math:pow(10, Pos-1))}).
```

The performance of this is around 100 times slower than using the `list_to_integer(binary_to_list(X))` option.